# Rails 4 migrate cancancan to pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm trying to migrate to Pundit and having a bit of trouble.

I have a user model and a photo model.

User has many photos and photo is a nested resource of user.
In my controller I do

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@photos = @user.photos
```

In my cancan ability class I have

```
can :create, Photo, :user => { :id => user.id }
```

and in a view I would use

```
<% if can? :create, @user => Photo %>
```

anyone know how to correctly do this with Pundit?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Only way I could get it to pass so far was adding a add_photo to the UserPolicy with record == user and in view doing `<% if policy(@user).add_photo? %>`

Answer (score 0):

Pundit approaches authorization differently than CanCan by providing authorization of objects. For starters, you'll want to write a PhotoPolicy:

```
class PhotoPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :photo

  def create?
    photo.user.id == user.id # Use photo.user_id if you have that column available 
  end    
end
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
<% if policy(@photo).create? %>
```

Notice that I'm calling this on a single `Photo`. If you want a policy for getting all the photos the user has access you would want to use a [scope](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). Let me know if this is the case and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Saul thanks for the answer and it makes sense.  Guess my main question would be.  If you have say /:company/tasks/:task_id how would you make sure the user has permission on the company and task?  For nested resources.  I am probably over thinking it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Writing polices really comes down to thinking through who can access what in your website. In the case of your companies/tasks question, it would depend. If a user belongs to a company, can they access all that company's tasks? Or only their own tasks for that company? The best way to get started if you're stuck is to write out a list of things user have access to and then start writing the policies from that list.